# Error document redirect htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect if a page does not exist. I have a .htaccess file with virtual subdomains, please help me.

This code isn't valid: `ErrorDocument 404 http://fisl.eu/`

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>

ErrorDocument 404 http://fisl.eu/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?fisl.eu$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|mail).fisl.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+).fisl.eu$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$ zoznam.php?category=%2&subcategory=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

order deny,allow
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex patter in both your rules are:

```
^([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$
```

Which matches pretty much everything. Change that to:

```
^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$
```

Now your `ErrorDocument 404` will work.